# How to assign the result of a SELECT query to a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Can't extract the value of the $row['PID'] from the query...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PID=(SELECT max(PID) FROM posts)");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$id = $row['PID'];
```

I know how to print it out:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['PID'];
      }
```

But no idea how to assign it to a variable without having to print it out...

Comment: in your while loop, without printing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second line, you are using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.
I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem (not used to sqli).

Can you do a `print_r` of the `$row` variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

to

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

to this:

`$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);`

Fetching an array will grab a multi dimensional array, so you'd have to use $row[0]['pid'] I believe.